# Eclipse errors on start-up and create Java project

Tags: eclipse

I've been having some trouble with Eclipse acting strangely the last couple of days.

The first thing I noticed was Java projects I had recently created weren't running from inside Eclipse.  Projects would compile with no errors and the .class files are created and run fine from the command line, but hitting the run or debug button in Eclipse produced no action at all. Old projects would run perfectly fine.

Then the errors started showing up.

I get this error sometimes on start-up:
[start up error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMvep.jpg)

I get this error every time I try to create a new Java project:
[create java project error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bEIE.jpg)

Here's the start of the log file (it's 12000 lines of this, I can post more if you ask):

```
!SESSION 2013-02-14 09:11:35.296 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800
java.version=1.7.0_13
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

This is a continuation of log file C:\Documents and Settings\team\workspace.metadata\.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2013-02-14 09:14:12.234

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2013-02-14 09:14:12.234
!MESSAGE Exception occurred while  unrendering:org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.PartImpl@67f9dcb7 (elementId: org.eclipse.pde.runtime.LogView, tags: [View, categoryTag:General], contributorURI: null) (widget: null, renderer: null, toBeRendered: true, onTop: false, visible: true, containerData: null, accessibilityPhrase: null) (contributionURI: bundleclass://org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView, object: null, context: null, variables: [], label: Error Log, iconURI: platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.ui.views.log//icons/eview16/error_log.gif, tooltip: , dirty: false, closeable: true, description: null)
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:63)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:859)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:839)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:368)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:127)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:76)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:107)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:70)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:170)
```

I tried starting up with a new workspace with no luck.  Today I've removed Java and Eclipse and started with a fresh Java JDK 7u13 and a fresh Eclipse Juno 4.2.1 download again with no luck. I have no idea what I've done here. Any ideas on what is causing this and how to fix it? I'm running Windows XP Professional x64 Edition if it matters.

Comment: I get this error sometimes on shut-down:
http://i.imgur.com/gHuclp4.jpg

Site won't let me use more than 2 links or put images directly in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always had trouble with 64-bit versions of Java. Might be worth trying a 32-bit install.

Comment: Thanks @tymeJV for the simple and easy fix.  With hearing about vulnerabilities every now and then my company likes us to keep our Java installs up to date for security reasons and I must have installed the 64 bit version because that is what my machine is.  Back to work after a day and half of banging my head against the desk :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but for a different reason. It looked like it was a 32/64 bit issue as I have Windows 7 X64, I got eclipse x64 and JDK1.7 X64, JRE1.6 x32 was already installed.
I eventually found out that I was re-using an old workspaces directory I created with the Google Android ADT Bundle which I'd setup a few weeks before and it doesn't like that.

So I thought I'd just share that little nugget.

Comment: Thank you. Setting up a new workspace and copying my old projects into it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Windows x64 not should be problems with Eclipse 64 bits always you have a JDKx64 installed. I recommend you use Eclipse 64-bit versions because you can allocate more memory in case you have projects that need.